# how to stores string in an array or Sequence?

Tags: linux, xslt

Im using xslt 1.0.
I have to store the string values in an array/sequence. Is there any way to declare a string array/sequence and store values in it??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using XSLT 2.0. It has much better support for such data types.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT does not have the same kind of variable support as other languages. An xsl:variable can only store a string, a number, a boolean value, or a node set. You can however create an XML array or sequence and use the key() function to perform a lookup:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xsltip.html